# Create histograms for three color channels separately in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, histogram, rgb

I have an assignment where I have to get a RGB image as the input and then draw **histograms** for three different channels (*Red*, *Green*, and *Blue*) separately using MATLAB.

Here is the code I wrote first:

```
function histogram_rgb(image)
    values1 = zeros(1, 256);    
    values2 = zeros(1, 256); 
    values3 = zeros(1, 256);

    [rows, cols, c] = size(image);

    for c1 = 1:rows
        for c2 = 1:cols
            values1(1, image(c1, c2, 1)) = values1(1, image(c1, c2, 1)) + 1;
            values2(1, image(c1, c2, 2)) = values2(1, image(c1, c2, 2)) + 1;
            values3(1, image(c1, c2, 3)) = values3(1, image(c1, c2, 3)) + 1;
        end
    end

    figure;
    subplot(1, 3, 1);
    bar((1:256), values1);
    title('Histogram for the Image - Red');

    subplot(1, 3, 2);
    bar((1:256), values2);
    title('Histogram for the Image - Green');

    size(values3)
    subplot(1, 3, 3);
    bar((1:256), values3);
    title('Histogram for the Image - Blue');
end
```

But this gave me the following error:

> > Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

I've searched for this error and found that it happens when array indexing goes wrong. Then I edited my code, which fixed that error. The only thing I did was edit the following line:

```
values3(1, image(c1, c2, 3)) = values3(1, image(c1, c2, 3)) + 1;
```

where the error was. All I did was to add 1 to the index, as follows:

```
values3(1, image(c1, c2, 3) + 1) = values3(1, image(c1, c2, 3) + 1) + 1;
```

My question is why does this happens? I mean, this index works fine for the first two arrays, then why not this one  Why does it run when I add 1 to the index?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many zero values are there in your image?

Comment: @beaker I don't know. I used four different images, all gave the same error. Hence I don't think that the number of zeros in the image may effect. Can it effect the indexing of the array ?

Comment: Absolutely. If you try to access `values3(1, 0)` you'll get the error above.

Comment: @beaker Oh, I see....... But what it doesn't failed in previous two arrays (`values1` and `values2`) ?

Comment: @beaker Can you post this as an answer, so I can accept it ?

Comment: My guess is that they other two channels didn't have any pixels that were 0 for that particular image. That's why you should always attach the input image so that people can reproduce your error. :) Anyway, your corrected code is what you should be doing anyway, mapping the 0..255 values of the image to 1..256 indices of the array.

Comment: @beaker No. I solved the problem, using your info. Thanks. I asked you to post these info as an answer, then I can accept it. Thanks again. :)

Comment: btw, it's generally a very bad idea to use a variable name which shadows a core function (e.g. `image`). Not to mention I spent ages trying to figure out why you're using an image object handle in an indexing operation xD. (also Matlab is case-sensitive, so you can use Image instead)

Comment: Also, presumably you're doing the histogram by hand because of your assignment, but just pointing out you can use the `hist` or `imhist` functions too. (e.g. `subplot(1,3,1); imhist(Image(:,:,1))` etc)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Yes. I know. But we were asked to write our own functions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity, the answer is that your image spans in intensity between `[0,255]` for some of the channels, but because MATLAB starts indexing at 1, any intensities in a channel that have the value of 0 will give you an out of bounds error.  This only happens for some of your channels and so that's why you don't see the error for the other channels. Therefore, you actually need to shift the intensity per channel by 1 to access the right element to populate in the matrix.  It should also be noted that if your image is an integer type, like `uint8`.  If you simply added 1, intensities that were already 255 will **saturate** to 255 and not go to 256.  Therefore, it's important that you temporarily cast the image to `double` when calculating the histogram before adding 1.

Therefore, in your double `for` loop, do this:

```
for c1 = 1:rows
    for c2 = 1:cols
        pix = double(image(c1, c2, :)) + 1; %  New
        values1(1, pix(1)) = values1(1, pix(1)) + 1; % Change
        values2(1, pix(2)) = values2(1, pix(2)) + 1; % Change
        values3(1, pix(3)) = values3(1, pix(3)) + 1; % Change
    end
end
```

What is nice with the above is that we convert all of the channels at a single location to `double` then add 1 to this after. We can then use each of the channels in this pixel to populate the histogram.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very simple task, provided using the `hist` function from matlab:

```
function histogram_rgb(image)
titles = {'R', 'G', 'B'};
for i=1:3
    subplot(1, 3, i);
    values = image(:, :, i);
    hist(values(:), 1:10:256);
    title(titles{i});
end
```

Comment: If you refer to the comment stream in the question above, the histogram calculation is an academic exercise so `hist` (or `imhist`) is not allowed to be used.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947676/create-histograms-for-three-color-channels-separately-in-matlab/38950018#comment65250927_38947676

Comment: This isn't an answer! As I stated, this is an academic assignment and I need to write my own histogram function.